# How to develop peer-to-peer chat application in browser

Tags: javascript, chat, p2p

I wish to develop a peer to peer chat application(in Javascript) in browser which uses some already developed javascript code for interaction to server. I have implemented web sockets but am facing problem developing chat app on this in browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peer to Peer is not (easily) possible with Javascript .. why no client-server?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Was it "Can somebody please direct me to some resources where I can learn how to code peer-to-peer applications with JS?" (Surely you didn't expect a complete tutorial or solution in an answer here?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to give you an idea of the simplest communication between to computers i can think of only using javascript, to give you some thoughts to get you started. From my understanding you want to use javascript for everything so here we go:

If you use Node.js this is the code:

```
var sys = require("sys"),  
my_http = require("http");  
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){  
    sys.puts("I got kicked");  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
    response.write("Hello World");  
    response.end();  
}).listen(8080);  
sys.puts("Server Running on 8080");
```

This makes a server listening to a port, and you can have it send and receive on this port. Put this on two pc's and you have communications between them already on the port of your choice.

Put some window to type the text and put a send button, and you are on your way. You stick your incoming in an array, that you show in your text window... in 3 hours you can have this up and running...

this is only to get you started on thinking about this... not my solution to how you should make a peer-to-peer chat application

Comment: Note that you can do the server-side coding in JS too. ([node.js](http://nodejs.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Play with Node.js

See http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial
Its a working chat example in Node only (JS rules!)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud create server to client to client chat. In server side use any language. In this tutorial use PHP for server side plase check
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/